# SSIS install as part of SQL Developer x86 installation?

Tags: sql-server-2005, windows-7, installation

I get the following error when trying to install SQL Server 2005 x86 Developer edition in the XP mode in windows 7 Professional.

MainEngineThread is returning 1645

Any thoughts/ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[XP Mode is the problem, perhaps](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927063)